# Multiple Forms to populate a single record access 2016

Tags: ms-access

I am using MS Access 2016 in an attempt to create a Form-driven database.

Suppose I have 2 forms - enter data into several Text Box's on Form One, then another form where user can keep updating/changing the record over time to update current status for only specific fields.

The problem I am facing is that data entered into Form One is placed in Record 1 on my Table, while data entered into Form Two is placed in the next Record (Record 2).

Question:  How can I create a string of Forms, but have the data inputted into each of those Forms show up on the same Record in the same Table?

**e.g. Form 1** has following fields
Name
Date
Style of Cause
Court File number
Status: "Open", "Close", "Re-Open"
Action Required
File Closure Summary
(and more 39 relevant fields)

**Form 2** (I need to update the same record for only selected fields )
Status: "Open", "Close", Re-Open"
Current Status Summary
Status Summary
File Closure Date
File Closure summary
Action Required
Key Lessons Learned

Comment: Open the next form using the ID of the first.

Comment: Instead of complication of multiple forms, maybe a single form with a Tab control? Name and Date are reserved words. Advise not to use reserved words as names as well as no spaces nor punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception).